# Changing/Appending Widgets contents

Tags: dart, flutter

I prefer using the below way for building the `Widget`, and I want to be able to modify the `children` of the column based on some parameters, i've 2 questions:

Is there any negative impact o doing it this way, rather than the way in the templates

And, Is the  `LayoutBuilder` the only available option to alert the `Widget`, as we are dealing with `final` parameters, that can not be used as `setters`!

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var _bar =  new AppBar(
          title: new Text(widget.title),
        );

    var _txt = new LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          if(constraints.maxWidth < 200.0) {
            return
              new Text(
                  "Rotate the screen pls",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1
              );
          } else {
            return
              new Text(
                  "Contents page",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1
              );
          }
        }
    );

    var _btnTxt = new Text(
        "ok",
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1
      );

    var _btn = new FlatButton(
        child: _btnTxt,
        textColor: new Color(0xFF66BB6A),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop('/home')
        );

    var _scf = new Scaffold(
      appBar: _bar,
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[_txt, _btn],
        ), 
      ),
    );

    return _scf;
  }
```

Comment: What you you mean by "The way in the templates" ?

Comment: And your second point is unreadable

Comment: @Darky  I mean having everything together as`      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times: $_counter'
            ),
            new Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),`

Comment: @Darky the second point, is there a way like `_scf.body..Chidlred.add/remove` !

Comment: I still don't understand the first point.

Comment: For the seconds, no. But you can store the children in a `<Widget>[]` and call `add` on it.

Comment: Thanks @Darky for th answer of the second point, sorry if my first one is not clear, let me rephrase it, do you see something wrong in my code:)

Comment: I would discourage mutating values that are passed to other widgets. Instead of adding to an existing list, create a new list that contains more widgets than the previous one and the framework will diff the two lists. You can still store previous children like @Darky is suggesting, but only use it as a source of previous children when building a new list; avoid mutating the list after it's been passed (to the `Column` widget in your example).